# Is there a purely functional implementation for a Bounded Queue with peek() in O(1)?

Tags: scala, queue, functional-programming

I want to maintain an immutable bounded FIFO queue from which I can remove the oldest values after a certain time. In Scala, the immutable.Queue works well for **size-bounded** queues (.size seems to be O(N) since it's internally based on List, but I can maintain the size separately), but there seems to be no cheap way to access the head element to test the age of the oldest value with anything cheaper than O(N), so I cannot test the expiration state of the oldest entry. Any pointers to a purely functional (immutable) implementation?

Answer (score 8):

This article, [Haskell: Queues without pointers](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/02/08/haskell-queues-without-pointers),
describes a purely functional queue with O(1) amortized cost (*edit*: for adding and removing elements). I think the data structure comes from Chris Okasaki and more details are in [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504).

The basic idea is to decompose the queue into *two* lists, one for the front and one for the back. New elements are added to "front". "Back" is stored in reverse order, to facilitate popping elements. When all elements of "back" are gone, "front" is reversed and re-identified as "back". This data structure has O(1) amortized cost for these operations, but apparently with some work it can be reduced to O(1), proper.

**Edit**: [Okasaki's paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) describes an elegant, purely functional implementation of queues and double-ended queues (deques). Deques allow adding or removing elements from either end. All such operations are O(1), worst case.

Comment: O(1) amortized cost of _what_? It doesn't make sense to speak of complexity of an operation without saying what that operation is. In this case, the operation is dequeuing, which is similar but not quite equal to peeking.

Comment: It is O(1) amortized cost for adding and removing elements. By peeking, you mean viewing the element at the top of the queue without removing it? This is easily implemented as a O(1) operation: For example, one can trivially add an extra field to the data structure that remembers the top element. Maintaining the size works the same way, as Alex mentions.

Comment: @Daniel, I now realize that you were referring to peeking into the element at the end of the queue. In my answer, this is just the head of the "back" list, so again O(1) time. If one needs to peek at multiple values at the end of the queue, one can make sure that "back" list is always sufficiently large.

Comment: Not back of the queue -- the oldest element will be the head of the queue. Adding an extra field is an interesting idea, and not one that depends on Okasaki's queue structure.

Comment: @Daniel, I reversed "back" and "front" terminology. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `immutable.Queue` in Scala can be adapted to work like that, for amortized complexity. Note, however, that the `peek` operation will return a new queue, or, otherwise, consecutive calls to `peek` might well all be done in O(n).

You can either extend `Queue` or create an altogether new class adapting it. Here's a version extending it:

```
import scala.collection._
import generic._
import immutable.Queue
import mutable.{ Builder, ListBuffer }

class MyQueue[+A] protected(in0: List[A], out0: List[A]) extends scala.collection.immutable.Queue[A](in0, out0) with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, MyQueue] with LinearSeqLike[A, MyQueue[A]] {
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[MyQueue] = MyQueue

  def peek: (A, MyQueue[A]) = out match {
    case Nil if !in.isEmpty => val rev = in.reverse ; (rev.head, new MyQueue(Nil, rev))
    case x :: xs            => (x, this)
    case _                  => throw new NoSuchElementException("dequeue on empty queue")
  }

  override def tail: MyQueue[A] =
    if (out.nonEmpty) new MyQueue(in, out.tail)
    else if (in.nonEmpty) new MyQueue(Nil, in.reverse.tail)
    else throw new NoSuchElementException("tail on empty queue")

  override def enqueue[B >: A](elem: B) = new MyQueue(elem :: in, out)

  // This ought to be override, but scalac doesn't think so!
  def enqueue[B >: A](iter: Iterable[B]) =
    new MyQueue(iter.toList.reverse ::: in, out)

  override def dequeue: (A, MyQueue[A]) = out match {
    case Nil if !in.isEmpty => val rev = in.reverse ; (rev.head, new MyQueue(Nil, rev.tail))
    case x :: xs            => (x, new MyQueue(in, xs))
    case _                  => throw new NoSuchElementException("dequeue on empty queue")
  }

  override def toString() = mkString("MyQueue(", ", ", ")")
}

object MyQueue extends SeqFactory[MyQueue] {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, MyQueue[A]] = new GenericCanBuildFrom[A]
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, MyQueue[A]] = new ListBuffer[A] mapResult (x => new MyQueue[A](Nil, x.toList))
  override def empty[A]: MyQueue[A] = EmptyQueue.asInstanceOf[MyQueue[A]]
  override def apply[A](xs: A*): MyQueue[A] = new MyQueue[A](Nil, xs.toList)

  private object EmptyQueue extends MyQueue[Nothing](Nil, Nil) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for a double-ended queue (*deque*). There is papers by Okasaki, Kaplan and Tarjan about purely functional deques. As for the implementations, the easiest is I think to take the default implementation of `collection.immutable.IndexedSeq` which is `collection.immutable.Vector`, according to [this table](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) having estimated constant costs for `head` and `last` (it says `tail` but i would guess that `last` is also O(1)).

The Okasaki/ Kaplan/ Tarjan one seems to have been implemented by [Henry Ware](http://code.google.com/p/scala-deque/).

The other implementation that comes to mind is the *FingerTree* by Hintze, for which various implementations in scala exist. [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) has one which some time ago I put into [a separate package](https://github.com/Sciss/FingerTree) since I use it a lot. According to a presentation by Daniel Spiewak (I don't remember where I saw this), the FingerTree is pretty slow though in the constant time factors -- and also the page by Henry Ware says that its slower than his other implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you do are looking for a double-ended queue (deque), Scala 1.13 (June 2019, eight years later) now have [`ArrayDeque`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayDeque.html)

> An implementation of a double-ended queue that internally uses a resizable circular buffer.
>
> Append, prepend, removeFirst, removeLast and random-access (indexed-lookup and indexed-replacement) take amortized constant time.
>
> In general, removals and insertions at `i`-th index are `O(min(i, n-i))` and thus insertions and removals from end/beginning are fast.

This comes from [`scala/collection-strawman` PR 490](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/pull/490), merged to Scala in [commit c0129af](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/commit/c0129af841eb698768a3fa7af902d7b869f95302).